# Why is "event.offsetX" undefined when "touchstart" event?

Tags: javascript, mobile, canvas, mobile-safari, hammer.js

I'm  trying to capture the position of the `touchstart` relative to an element (".canvas")
Is there any possibility to capture this event `offsetX` and `offsetY`?

```
$(".canvas").on("mousemove", function(event){
     console.log(event.offsetX + " - " + event.offsetY);
})
```

With `click` event:
http://jsfiddle.net/jfejc6zw/1/

With `touchstart` event (Test it with your mobile or simulator)
http://jsfiddle.net/jfejc6zw/2/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

If you're already using jQuery, why would you bother with the low level event coordinates? Just use the jQuery [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset) and [.position()](http://api.jquery.com/position) functions, in the knowledge that jQuery already did all the browser-inconsistency solving.

Comment: `offset()` only gives the position of the jQuery element. offsetX/offsetY give the position of the *event* relative to the element they were triggered on.